# How to integrate Mailchimp with Ionic app?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an Ionic app and I am trying to integrate mailchimp. I am using the embedded forms and they work whenever I run it on the browser (ionic serve) but whenever I test on a native device it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks.

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>


<!--<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
  <input type="email">
</label>-->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//[businessname].[dc].list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=[list]&amp;id=39c3c32163" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h3 class="padding">Don’t Miss Out on the Top Stories from Each Week!</h3>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL" class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Email Address: </span>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group" >
    <label for="mce-FNAME" class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">First Name: </span>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group" >
    <label for="mce-LNAME" class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Last Name: </span>
    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group" >
    <label for="mce-MMERGE9" class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">State: </span>
    <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE9" class="" id="mce-MMERGE9">
  </label>
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_1b57193ff878b1601ed47f497_39c3c32163" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button button-positive button-block"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[9]='MMERGE9';ftypes[9]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two lines. Add #form to form tag and (click)="form.submit()" to input tag:

```
<form #form action="//[businessname].[dc].list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=[list]&amp;id=39c3c32163" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button button-positive button-block" (click)="form.submit()">
```